# FuelPHP not showing any errors

Tags: php, fuelphp

I've been using FuelPHP for some time, and I think I may have done something wrong this time because after installing composer and getting things up and running, I no longer see any errors outputed to the browser.

This is what I see ANYTIME there is an error:

```
 Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

YES, I have errors showing for PHP with this:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It's almost like it cannot find my error... Does anyone have any suggestions? It's quite frustrating to debug without any info... :-) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem. If anyone should know, it is because of file ownerships on my root directory were off... I also ran composer update to be safe. After doing this I am finally able to see proper errors again.

I fixed it with the following Shell command:

```
 > chown -R MyUser:MyGroup MyRootDirectory/*
```

Then I ran composer udpate:

```
 > composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

To be complete: you get this error because there is a fatal error in the shutdown handler, which is used by FuelPHP to process session output, file downloads, and log entries.

For log files, the Log class is now checking if it has write access to app/logs before attempting to write. Session (file based) doesn't, it will throw an exception.